# am I safe to upgrade my cocos2d 2.1 game to XCode 6 to support iPhone 6?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have been working on a game that is 95% done, and have been working in Snow Leopard with XCode 5.0.2, intentionally not upgrading to prevent any complications since I am so close.  My other team mate got a new computer with mavericks and was using XCode 6, and so I attempted to upgrade XCode to 5.1.1--- when I did this, my entire project was full of errors and a disaster...

My question is, if I plan to release my game and have it tested on a new iPhone 6, do I need to install Mavericks + XCode?  I absolutely do not want to go through the pain of upgrading my game to cocos2d 3.0, and I am afraid if I try to run a 2.1 game on the latest XCode its all going to blow up and not work (just as it did even with 5.1.1).........

Comment: Blow up? Why aren't you using source control? I usually don't upgrade in the middle of projects but even if you did you should have a working commit before you attempted the upgrade.

Comment: Of course I am using version control.  I'm saying I don't want to have to go through what seems to be a completely unnecessary upgrade; i.e. the game works great, and upgrading will accomplish nothing except make it not work great.

Comment: I can understand that. If you don't need anything from the upgrade, I'd wait until the project was done and submitted personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to submit your App to the app store, you are going to have to submit it using at least Xcode 5.1.1

[image]